# Python: Extract specific number of characters after delimeters

Tags: python, regex, split

I have a file with multiple lines of a fix syntax. Each line of file looks like this:

```
13:09:04.210262 2.0 Mb/s 2412 MHz 11g -22dB signal antenna 7 BSSID:00:00:00:12:34:56 (oui Unknown) DA:01:23:45:67:89:78 (oui Unknown) SA:89:12:33:45:b3:11 (oui Unknown)
```

I want to grab some specific number of characters (MAC addresses) after the two (':') delimiters from each line and save them into strings. So far I have this:

```
searchfile = open("tcpdump_deauth.txt", "r")
for line in searchfile:
  ssid, dest_mac, src_mac = line.split(':')
```

It should give me all the substrings which I can further process to get the MAC addresses but it is a complex way. Can someone guide me how to fix it or maybe suggest a better way to do the tasK?

I also have "DA" and "SA" showing up on all lines so I can try using Regex if that is a better idea.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution:

```
lst = re.findall('(?:DA|SA|BSSID):(\S+)', line)
```

`\S+` means any non-white space characters. `(?:DA|SA|BSSID)` means any of `DA`, `SA` or `BSSID`.

But if you want to match the actual MAC, then you can use this one:

```
lst = re.findall('(?:DA|SA|BSSID):([a-fA-F0-9]{2}(?::[a-fA-F0-9]{2}){5})', line)
```

You can get the explanation of the regex using [this link](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl).

For both cases, the lst holds:

```
['00:00:00:12:34:56', '01:23:45:67:89:78', '89:12:33:45:b3:11']
```

Comment: It works. But can I ask how are the number of non-white space characters to capture are controlled?

Comment: `\S+` is for length 1 to any. If you want to limit it, then have to use `\S{1,100}` means length `1-100`.

Answer (score 3):

you should be able to match using the following regex:

```
>>> r = re.compile('.*BSSID:([0-9A-F:]+) .*DA:([0-9A-F:]+) .*SA:([0-9A-F:]+)', re.IGNORECASE)
>>> r.match(s).groups()
('00:00:00:12:34:56', '01:23:45:67:89:78', '89:12:33:45:b3:11')
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Run it live](https://www.debuggex.com/r/axPqct0luOjhnrQ8)

btw, you can also get them as a dictionary using the following snippet:

```
>>> r = re.compile('.*BSSID:(?P<BSSID>[0-9A-F:]+) .*DA:(?P<DA>[0-9A-F:]+) .*SA:(?P<SA>[0-9A-F:]+)', re.IGNORECASE)
>>> r.match(s).groupdict()
{'BSSID': '00:00:00:12:34:56', 'DA': '01:23:45:67:89:78', 'SA': '89:12:33:45:b3:11'}
```

so basically, you can then build a list of dicts:

```
datagrams = []
for line in searchfile:
  datagrams.append(r.match(s).groupdict())
```

and then, for example, get all the source macs:

```
for d in datagrams:
  print d['SA']
```

Answer (score 3):

Regular expression '(DA:\w{2}:\w{2}:\w{2}:\w{2}:\w{2}:\w{2})' will return the MAC address 'DA:01:23:45:67:89:78'. 
You can do a similar thing for SA.